# infimum of the set formed by n-1/n

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Consider the set $A = \left\{n - \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. Find the $\inf A$ and $\sup A$.

Clearly this set has infimum of $\,0\,$ and a non-existent supremum (or infinite). My question is not limited to this set in particular, but how does one approach a question like this? I've seen and read so many answers for inf and sup questions that seem to pull things from thin air and I'm trying to understand a thought process behind the approaches.

My personal intuition for this problem would be to show that for any $\epsilon$ $> 0$, $\epsilon$ cannot be a lower bound of the set. I tried using the Archimedean principal but I seem to get stuck on how to employ it to achieve my goal.

I know this problem can be approached by proving the set is monotonically increasing (thus proving the sup cannot exist and the infimum will be the smallest element of the set), but based on the way I thought of the problem ,how can I succeed?

Comment: Do you mean $\epsilon$ cannot be an *upper* bound of the set? The lower bound of $0$ doesn't require such an argument.

Comment: I see what you mean. How then would I show that 0 is the infA? That "intuition" that I spoke of, in my mind, was to show that 0 is the greatest lower bound, so would I instead need to show that anything less than 0 cannot be the inf?. I'm struggling to approach these problems systematically (I feel as though the solutions are random when I know that they are not)

Comment: inf$A:=0$ as $0$ is the greatest number smaller or equal to every element of your set, whilst the sup does not exists as you have the elements tend to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Recall the definitions of infimum and supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your general question, I would say that there are a few things that you might try. The most general approach that I find helpful is to examine the first few values and, in this way, to try and better understand the set that you are looking at.

Another approach is to try and rewrite an expression like the one that you have in a helpful manner. For example, the expression $n - \frac{1}{n}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{n^2 - 1}{n}$. As the values of $n$ increase, we find the numerator increasing quadratically but the denominator increasingly linearly; this suggests the values just get bigger and bigger (in such a situation, the inf comes early and the sup may be undefined – as per your own observations).

One more technique: Although you may often encounter sets defined in terms of natural numbers (or integers) it can be fruitful to consider extending the domain to e.g. all real numbers. In this particular case, you might consider the function $x \mapsto x - \frac{1}{x}$ and, specifically, its derivative; alternatively, you could graph such a function as done [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e7lejc3evi) for $x \geq 1$.

For each of the approaches outlined above, you are led back to your same initial observation: The infimum occurs for $n=1$ and there is no supremum since the sequence monotonically increases to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your insight this helps tremendously! I think the fact of starting with our conclusion and working to a logical place to start to bring us to said conclusion makes a lot of sense.

Comment: $n-\frac 1n>n-1$ is probably more straightforward

Comment: @zwim Agreed. I mostly want to emphasize that rewriting an expression can be a useful general technique (which is what the OP asks about).